# How to Pass the HTML code via export statment in shell script

Tags: shell, sed, export

I am trying to Export the HTML code via variable to the antoher file, but while trying to exprot i am getting the message like .

Value i am going to export

```
> VALUESTRING=<a class="modal::content:serviceloc:width:780:height:500 button lq_login"></a>
```

Error Message:

```
>line 13: lq_login"': not a valid identifier  line 13:
> export: `<span': not a valid identifier
```

Any one could you check on this.

Answer (score 0):

use proper quotes for variable value:

```
export VALUESTRING='<a class="modal::content:serviceloc:width:780:height:500 button lq_login"></a>'
```

Comment: I am exporting the variable of another vairable as below: export ${keystring}="${valuestring}" , values are getting replaced but, this not a valid identifier message is coming running the script

Comment: I tried that anishsane , i am not getting the expected output..what is the use eval command before export command , some forums recommend this eval before export to eleminate the this message, could you please give the clear idea on this.

Comment: but still i am getting the not valid identifier message, could you help me on this............